# Placing of a JavaScript resource file

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML file which use AngularJs javascript file. And I run this application using `Tomcat 7`

```
<html>
  <head> 
    <script src="src/main/resources/appjs/angular.min.js"></script> // not working
    <script src="/resources/appjs/angular.min.js"></script> // not working
    <script src="/src/main/resources/appjs/angular.min.js"></script> // not working

    <!-- <script src="angular.min.js"></script> --> // working
  </head>
  <body>
  <h2>Hello World!</h2>


  <div ng-app="">
      <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
      <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

If I put the JS file in that separate folder it wont work. And If I put it inside the same directory it will work.
What could be the reason for this behavior ?

Comment: it is because both those files are in the same directory(you have both angular js file amd html file under "webapp"  folder)

Comment: @LuthandoLoot but if the path is correct then it should work r8 
?

Comment: I mean can't I place JS files outside the webapp folder ?

Comment: this would work `/resources/appjs/angular.min.js` not htis `src/main/resources/appjs/angular.min.js`

Comment: As I haven't used tomcat, I couldn't say for sure. But generally, no, for security reasons. If you could, you could also request your java source code files, which wouldn't be desired I assume?

Comment: Does going to [domain-name-here]/src/main/resources/appjs/angular.min.js work?

Comment: going to [domain-name-here]/src/main/resources/appjs/angular.min.js `is also not working`

Answer (score 1):

When giving relative paths with out '/' in the beginning  it will start looking for the file relative to the folder where html is present. In you case there is angular.min.js where index.html is located so it works other doesn't.

Comment: I edited the question. it happens if i remove '/' also.

Answer (score 0):

Your server will be configured to serve files from the "src/main/resources/appjs" directory.  If you set the `src` for your `<script>` to "angular.min.js" then the server will dish it up fine.. but if you set the `src` to "src/main/resources/appjs/angular.min.js" then the server is looking for "src/main/resources/appjs/src/main/resources/appjs/angular.min.js", which doesn't exist.

Absolute paths are specified by a URL beginning with a "/", so if you try "/src/main/resources/appjs/angular.min.js" it may work - although security may be an issue and "src" may not be in the root-level directory of your server.

Comment: the src path `<script src="/src/main/resources/appjs/angular.min.js"></script>` does not work either.

Comment: As I explained, either security is preventing access to absolute paths or `src` is not in the root of your server.

Comment: So is there any way to change that ? I mean `or src is not in the root of your server.` this ?

Comment: As I said in comments above, allowing src to be accessed seems a bit odd, since you'd also be able to access your java source files. What's stopping you from putting it in the webapp folder?